Finding a mis-formed XML tag (missing start or end tag) in Oracle SQL

Blockquote

To this end I have tried this SQL :"
    With Tab (T1) AS
  (
SELECT  C.* from  bph_owner.paymentinterchange pint,
   XMLTABLE(
     'declare default element namespace "urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.008.001.02";
          //FinInstnId ' 
           PASSING XMLtype(pint.transportdata, nls_charset_id('AL32UTF8')) 
              )   C
                where pint.referenceidx='JH1104Defect19139b' 
                )
       select * from Tab where  instr(Tab.T1,'>/<') > 0 
  ;


Blockquote
against  a BLOB that contains :

> <Document xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.008.001.02"
> xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
> xsi:schemaLocation="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.008.001.02
> pain.008.001.02.xsd">   <CstmrDrctDbtInitn>
>     <GrpHdr>
>       <MsgId>JH1104Defect19139b</MsgId>
>       <CreDtTm>2016-06-02T08:25:59</CreDtTm>
>       <NbOfTxs>1</NbOfTxs>
>       <CtrlSum>0.06</CtrlS

.... other stuff (sensitive) until we get to

    <CdtrAgt>
      <FinInstnId/>
    </CdtrAgt>


I am trying to identify the

      <FinInstnId/> with no  <FinInstnId>


But  I cannot get to identify it."

Blockquote

If I use
   with q1 ( Tdata) AS (
    SELECT XMLtype(transportdata, nls_charset_id('AL32UTF8')) 
  from   bph_owner.paymentinterchange pint 
  where pint.referenceidx='JH1104Defect19139b' 
  )
  SELECT 
  XMLQuery(
     'declare default element namespace "urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.008.001.02";
          //FinInstnId ' 
           PASSING Tdata
            returning content).getstringval()
     from q1
  ;


Blockquote

I can get output like this :

Blockquote

<FinInstnId xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.008.001.02" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/><FinInstnId xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.008.001.02" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">RBOSGB20</FinInstnId>
The  line shows an end tag but no start tag (for the second FinInstnID) which is what I ma trying to identify!

Blockquote
Is there a way to find this malformed tag?


Many thanks"


Please update the tags with the rdbms you're using. Is it Oracle? Your tags won't help others like you track this question for a possible solution. I recommend to add xml, syntax-error in addition to the name of the rdbms.
